# Warning "Something went wrong" appears every time I try to enable a theme

Tags: magento-2.1

**Preconditions**

Magento 2.1.0, php 5.6, MariaDB 10

**Steps to reproduce**

When I press on `Content > Design > Configuration` I get the error

**Expected result**: list of themes to enable one of them

**Actual result**: A pop up displays the warning:

> Attention. Something went wrong

and when I tracked the error, I found this:

> Warning: strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /home/nibrasac/public_html/magento2.1/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Column.php
>   on line 136

Comment: Have you performed a Magento Compile? Including a flush of the `var` (`di`/`generation`) folders?

Comment: Look for the strtoupper() in the theme and see what argument you are passing in there. Warning clearly says that strtoupper is expecting string but an array is provided.